# Normal text in Theorem?

Tags: theorems, text

How do I write normal text just for a small portion in the Theorem environment? Ive tried \text{} and nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please post a minimal, compilable, code?

Comment: `\textup` will revert to upright from italic shape

Comment: @Andrew `\textrm` switches family but (assuming the issue is that the theorem is in italic) you need to switch shape not family.

Comment: `\emph{...} should also work.  This would be appropriate for a phrase that would be italic in an upright environment, or upright in an italic environment, e.g. for a biological name.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. Deleted.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because 1) it needs more clarity and 2) is seems to be solved in comments.